# Why does my Chrome Developer Tools show me variable value like this?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-developer-tools

Most often than not, I am seeing variable values like in below image in Chrome Developer Tools. Why do you think this is? Can you let me know of a possible setting where this can be reset to the original proper settings?
I have tried resetting to factory default which does not help.

[image: cannot see variable value]